# need to label columns in order to get rid of NA columns: NAs numbered

Tags: regex, r, file-handling, na

I have two files that I have to link together.

```
   > dim(sample.details)
   [1] 656  18
   > dim(E.rna)
   [1] 47323   656
```

My job is to label the column names of one file data frame with the values in a column from the other.

```
 ptr <- match( colnames(E.rna), sample.details$my_category_2 )
 sample.details <- sample.details[ptr,] # reorder to correspond to rows of E.RNA
 rownames(E.rna)<-outcome
```

My problem is that now that I have labeled the columns of E.rna properly. I need to get rid of the values that are 'NA'. The below command doesn't work unfortunately...

```
 E.rna_conditions_cleaned<-subset(E.rna, !is.na(colnames(E.rna)))
```

This is because the relabelling of the columns has only relabelled the columns with NA values as "NA.1, NA.2, NA.3...." so I can't get rid of them with 'na.omit'.

[image]

Can I somehow use regular expressions to consecutively get rid of the NA columns...? My idea would be as follows:

```
 subset(df, any df column name that does not == 'NA' followed by a 1-3 digit number)
```

I am not familiar with regex... Any tips?

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example and expected output?  Try `df[!grepl("^NA\\.\\d+", names(df))]`  In the `subset`, you have to use `select` for selecting the columns and it can be either named or numeric vector.

Comment: Hi Akrun so do you mean: " E.rna_conditions_cleaned<-subset(E.rna, !is.na(colnames(E.rna)), select= df[!grepl("^NA\\.\\d+", names(df))]) " ?

I will update the question accordingly thanks

Comment: Thank you Akrun I did it with "E.rna_conditions_cleaned<-E.rna_conditions_cleaned[!grepl("^NA\\.\\d+", names(E.rna_conditions_cleaned))]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `grepl` with pattern that matches `NA` followed by a dot (`.`) followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) on the column names, negate the logical output and use it to subset the columns.

```
E.rna_conditions_cleaned<-E.rna_conditions_cleaned[!grepl("^NA\\.\\d+",
          names(E.rna_conditions_cleaned))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following regex:

```
# build sample df
E.rna <- data.frame(U.95=1:5, HC.54=letters[6:10], NA.5=rnorm(5), KD.77=runif(5))

# get rid of unwanted variables
E.rna_conditions_cleaned <- E.rna[, grep("^NA", names(E.rna), invert=TRUE)]
```

The `grep` function finds the indices of the variables that match the pattern "^NA" (names start with NA) invert=TRUE takes the complement of these indices (those that do not match the pattern).